# Hive: Find top 20 percent records

Tags: hadoop, hive, bigdata, hiveql

I have some data like:-

```
ID  PRICE
1   100
2   200
3   120
4   130
5   320
6   300
7   200
8   100
9   120
10  250
```

I need to find top 20% price.

Expected output:-

```
ID  PRICE
5   320
6   300
```

Comment: please include your attempt as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without joins. Use analytic function to calculate `max(price)`, take 80%, then use filter price>80%:

```
with your_data as ( --this is your data
select stack(10,
1 ,  100,
2 ,  200,
3 ,  120,
4 ,  130,
5 ,  320,
6 ,  300,
7 ,  200,
8 ,  100,
9 ,  120,
10,  250) as (ID,  PRICE)
)

select id, price 
from
(
select d.*, max(price) over()*0.8 as pct_80 from your_data d
)s where price>pct_80
```

Result:

```
OK
id      price
6       300
5       320
```

Use your table instead of `WITH` subquery, add order by **ID** if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Below would be the queries -

```
with top_20 as (
  select 
    max(price)*0.8 as price1 
  from 
    <tableName>
)
select * from <tableName> t1 , top_20 t2 where t1.price > t2.price1;

select 
 name, 
 price 
from 
 (select 
    name, 
    price, 
    max(price)*0.8 over (order by price) as top_20 
 from <tableName>
 ) t1 
where 
 t1.price > t1.top_20;
```

Below query will not work in hive -

```
select * from <tableName> where price > (select max(salary)*0.8 from <tableName>)

select * from <tableName> t1 where exists (select salary from <tablename> t2 where t1.salary > t2.salary*0.8)
```

Reason - Hive does not support sub query in where clause with equal condition, it supports with only IN, NOT IN , EXISTS and NOT EXISTS.

Even with Exists and NOT Exists, it supports only Equijoin, Refer https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+SubQueries#LanguageManualSubQueries-SubqueriesintheWHEREClause for more details

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Heres a way in which you're able to do it without having to use `join`.

```
Select id,price from (select id,price, row_number() over(order by price desc) r1,count(*) over()*(20/100) ct from table_name)final where r1<=ct ;
```